# MS Access - change table/query that another query is based on

Tags: ms-access-2010

I will have an Access database where I have to import a new table every day. The table name has the date in it, e.g. `Table1_100815`, so the one tomorrow would be called `Table1_110815`.

I will also have a query which will be exactly the same every day, except obviously the table name will change.

Is there a way of automating the change of table name in the query, or would I have to change the query every day manually?

Many thanks

Comment: Are you talking about a saved query or a query which you build at run-time with VBA code?  And how do you use the query afterward?

Comment: You can always import the table in such a way that the resulting table has a consistent name. Or, you could import the table with a new name every day and just rename the table to some consistent name before running your query.

Comment: Thanks for your answers so far. I am tallking about a saved query. Essentially I get an updated datasheet everyday that includes multiple rows of data for multiple days, so on day10 I would get all the data from day 1 to 10, on day 11 all data from day 1 to 11 etc. I need to save all previous days tables, but run the same queries everyday. Is there any way you can use something like a form to select the table to use in a query?